# UK Stamp Duty - corona virus changes

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, mortgage

I am about to buy ***my first house in UK*** with my girlfriend (price is £250,000)

I also own a house in Poland, that my dad gave me in his will (its value is over £40,000)

Recently it was announced in UK, that anyone buying a house that will be his main residence, will pay no stamp duty if price is below £500,000.

I find so many conflicting opinions, one saying that I indeed will not have to pay stamp duty, while other saying I will have to pay 3% of the purchase price, in this case it would be £7,500

Do I need to pay stamp duty, in shed of recent UK stamp duty holiday that government introduced?

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I am neither a financial advisor nor a lawyer. This is neither financial nor legal advice!*

> Do I need to pay stamp duty, in [light] of recent UK stamp duty holiday that government introduced?

It looks like you **will** have to pay Stamp Duty at 3% on the purchase price of £250,000, *although you may be able to claim it back* if you sell your property in Poland within three years.

---

The "main page" on the Gov.UK website, [**Stamp Duty Land Tax**](https://www.gov.uk/stamp-duty-land-tax/residential-property-rates) covers the "normal" position, but currently (28th July 2020) starts with:

> From 8 July 2020 the [SDLT threshold for residential properties is changing](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-temporary-reduced-rates). This page will be updated soon.

The linked page, [**Stamp Duty Land Tax: temporary reduced rates**](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-temporary-reduced-rates) includes two sections of interest:

> **Residential Rates on purchases from 8 July 2020 to 31 March 2021**
>
> If you purchase a residential property between 8 July 2020 to 31 March 2021, you only start to pay SDLT on the amount that you pay for the property above £500,000. These rates apply whether you are buying your first home or have owned property before.

> **Higher rates for additional properties**
>
> The 3% higher rate for purchases of additional dwellings applies on top of revised standard rates above for the period 8 July 2020 to 31 March 2021.

So, for the time being, whether you are a first-time buyer or not, you would not normally pay any Stamp Duty on a £250,000 house. However, the house you own in Poland complicates things. From the main page on SDLT (my first link, emphasis mine):

> **If you’re replacing your main residence**
>
> You will not pay the extra 3% SDLT if the property you’re buying is replacing your main residence and **that has already been sold**.
>
> If you have not sold your main residence on the day you complete your new purchase you’ll have to pay higher rates. This is because you own 2 properties.
>
> **You can apply for a refund if you sell your previous main home within 36 months**.
>
> > There are [special rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-buying-an-additional-residential-property) if you own property with someone else or already own a property outside England, Wales and Northern Ireland.

The "special rules" page, [**Higher rates of Stamp Duty Land Tax**](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-buying-an-additional-residential-property) includes (my emphasis):

> You must pay the higher SDLT rates when you buy a residential property (or a part of one) for £40,000 or more, if all the following apply:
>
> - it will not be the only residential property worth £40,000 or more that you own (or part own) **anywhere in the world**
> - you have not sold or given away your previous main home
> - no one else has a lease on it which has more than 21 years left to run

So, as you *are* buying a (residential) property worth more than £40,000, and you *do* own another property *anywhere in the world* valued at over £40,000, and will not have sold that property on the day you buy the new one, *you will have to pay 3% on the purchase price of £250,000 (= £7,500)*.

If you are intending to sell the property in Poland (or end up doing so) within three years, the page [**Apply for a repayment of the higher rates of Stamp Duty Land Tax**](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/stamp-duty-land-tax-apply-for-a-repayment-of-the-higher-rates-for-additional-properties) goes into the details of how to apply for a refund. *Note*: although that page mentions being able to claim outside the three-year period in "exceptional circumstances", including COVID-19, I doubt that that will apply since the three-year clock won't start ticking until you buy the house in the UK.